# Home ethernet connection problem

Tags: ethernet, interference, networking

I had a technician wire my house with ethernet cables which all connect to a TPLink hub. My hope was to have a wired internet connection in a few of the rooms. The cables are around 10 meters each.

The cables are connected, and I have a good internet connection at the hub, but nothing at the other end of the cables. I tried grounding the cables, but nothing happened.

Are there any tests I can run to figure out what's wrong? If it is interference, could better hardware solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: What does your cable tester say?

Comment: The tech's tester shows a live connection. Perhaps it has a better hardware than the common PC's?

Comment: Why the heck would you use a hub rather than a switch?

Comment: This is not an electronic engineering question.  It might be better on SuperUser.

Comment: Does your "electrician" normally handle Cat5/6 wiring?  My immediate guess is that his tester shows continuity on all 4 pairs, but doesn't show pairing errors.

Comment: Is the "hub" actually a router with DHCP? If not, you are likely not going to get things to work right. You need a broadband router to properly do what you are trying. Can you please clarify what TPLink model you are using?

Comment: If the electrician didn't know what he was doing (or was color-blind) then likely the colors are not assigned to the pin locations properly.  You need a proper cable tester.  But, as others have said, if you can unplug the other end from the "hub", plug it directly into the modem, and are then able to connect through that cable, then it's likely the "hub".

Comment: Do you get a link light on the NICs?  I'm kind of afraid to ask, but how exactly did you "ground" the cables?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good question -- how do you "ground" cat5/6 cables??

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. As for grounding the cable: I tried connecting the cable shield to the grounding used by the power outlet. I'll try to get a proper cable tester (and a proper technician?) and test the connection.

Comment: It's unusual for cat5/6 cable to have a shield.  Most RJ45 connectors are not designed to provide grounding for a shield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One step at a time:

1. Get a known good cable, connect one end directly to your DSL modem or whatever, and connect a computer (hopefully something portable like a laptop) to the other end.  If you cannot connect to the internet through that connection then your modem is not set up properly (or you don't know which outlet there to plug into).
2. If that works, unplug from the modem, plug into the "hub" instead, and run a cable from the modem to the "hub".  See if that works.
3. If you get this far the cables are suspect, and you need a proper cable tester.

Answer (score 1):

Either the hub (switch?) is bad, or the wiring is bad. To determine which it is, try plugging the computer directly into each of the ports on the hub using a short Ethernet patch cable.

If all of the ports work, then the problem is in the wiring. Call the technician back and have him do it right.

If not, the hub must either be bad or not configured/powered correctly.

In the meantime, try connecting each of the cables to the rooms directly to the Internet router/modem one at a time, and verify that you can get access to the Internet from the corresponding room. If that works in every room, then the wiring is fine, and the hub really is the problem.

In any case, questions on the use of electronic equipment are off-topic for this site (EE.SE).